# How to navigate back from text/binary file view in Vim's Netrw directory listing?

Tags: vim, gvim

I use `vim.gtk3 .` to navigate current directory in **Netrw Directory Listing** view.

[image]

I know I can press <kbd>x</kbd> to act like `xdg-open`. I also know I can press <kbd>-</kbd> to navigate to parent directory.

But if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `mp4` binary file, it will show in binary view:
[image]

Or if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a **C** text file, it will show in normal code view:
[image]

At this point (binaries or code view),  how to use shortcut key and get back to **previous Netrw Directory Listing page**? I pressed <kbd>-</kbd> and it doesn't work. I have to type `:q` to quit the entire `vim.gtk3`.

**Is it possible go back directory listing page from text view after pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Netrw Directory Listing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_explorer) you should be able to do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> however it doesn't work on my system, it will only alternate between files. You can pull up a fresh explorer via `:Explore` or `:e .`